# Using regex to determine conversions for various dynamic URLs

Tags: regex, google-analytics, web-analytics

this stuff is over my head and I hope someone can help me. Thank you for your time in advance!!

I want to determine different types of conversions based on the success URL. I have two types:

a. A job was posted on the site
b. A new tradesman has signed up

These are the two success URLs:

a. A job was posted
Unique URL: http://www.redfish.co.za/job/Some-Variable-Job-Name/success

b. A new tradesman registered
Unique URL: http://www.redfish.co.za/tradesman/Some-Variable-Trademan-Name/success

So the first regex function should looks at the URL and determine whether the URL contains the word /job/ AND /success

The second regex function should allow me to tell whether the URL contains the word /tradesman/ AND /success

Please, can you help me? I have tried to work from other examples given here but don't understand this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

URL contains the word /job/ AND /success

```
/\/job\/.*\/success/
```

[jsFiddle](https://regex101.com/r/tA8qA2/1)

URL contains the word /tradesman/ AND /success

```
/\/tradesman\/.*\/success/
```

[jsFiddle](https://regex101.com/r/mU6bB3/1)

Explanation:

- `/`  Indicates that what follows is a regex
- '/' / has a special meaning in regular expressions (see above), so it needs to be escaped with \
- `job` These exact characters
- `\/`  A second /, to complete the word `/job/`
- `.*` Zero or more characters (anything except a newline character)
- `\/success`  The string `/success`, with the `\` character escaped
- `/`  Indicates the end of the regex

Comment: Just a tiny, small note. Questioneer asked about "/success" and not for "/success/" for URLs. Might want to do a quick edit just to clear it up. I couldn't fix it for you since edits needs to be 6 characters.